# Sharepoint authentication with python

Tags: python, authentication, sharepoint, request

I'm trying to use python to download an excel file that is hosted in a sharepoint which is part of the **Microsoft Azure platform**. I tried to retrieve the file with HTTPforhumans's `request` by doing:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

But my requests keep getting denied (`r.status_code` returns `200`) because I need to login to a valid account before trying to access the file. I do have a valid account and password, and I can access to my account and to the excel file via the browser. But I have no idea how to deal wit the Azure authentication procedure. And apparently it is not as easy as just doing:

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('email@somewhere.com', 'pass1234')
r = requests.post(url=url, auth=auth)
```

It is my uderstanding that there's a flow to follow, but when I try to read the documentation, it just goes over my head (I'm an engineer and I do not have experience in this kind of environment).

Can someone guide me in the process of how to login and download the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [O365 rest python client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/) [library](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/).it supports [SharePoint Online authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/authentication) and allows to download/upload a file as demonstrated below: Please find the code here:

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username,password)   
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
response = File.open_binary(context, "/Shared Documents/User Guide.docx")
with open("./User Guide.docx", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)
```

You can download the latest version using below command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client.git
```

For further reference please visit [link](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/file_operations.py)

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it seems to work. Nonetheless now I'm getting: `Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access ''` - Which I guess has more to do with the configuration that my organization has. I'll be posting a new question with this issue.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please feel free to open new thread and tag me , will be happy to assist.