# How to Access A SharePoint List with OAuth2

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint

I have the following code that I believe would work for most sharepoint sites, but am receiving the following error:

*Exception("Check username/password and rootsite")*

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com'
username = 'user123@company.com'
password = 'password'
listname = 'Test List'


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
   ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
   web = ctx.web
   sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(listname)
   items = sp_list.get_items()
   ctx.load(items)
   ctx.execute_query()

else:
   print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
```

How would I manipulate this code to ensure that I can pull data from a SharePoint List into Python?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client#Working-with-SharePoint-API)

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
    from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

    ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
    if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
      ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
      web = ctx.web
      sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(listname)
      items = sp_list.get_items()
      ctx.load(items)
      ctx.execute_query()
      # to do

    else:
      print ctx_auth.get_last_error()
```

Comment: I followed this (original code updated), but am now receiving an error on the if statement: KeyError: 'FedAuth' - any thoughts?

Comment: This answer addresses the 'FedAuth' issue by using the "app-only" flow supported by Office365-REST-Python-Client: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55955080/5350621