# Check user credentials for a sharepoint site with multi-factor authentication

Tags: python, authentication, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to check if a user can log in to a specific sharepoint site using their user credentials.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
try: 
    if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("email", "password"):
        print("Get access")        
except:
    print("access denied")
```

But this sharepoint site uses multiple factor authentication and I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access ''
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922791/azure-sharepoint-multi-factor-authentication-with-python) had a similar problem and the answer was to use a generated "client_id" and 'client_secret'

In addition to this, I also have to check the user credentials to grant a user access.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if MFA is enabled for SharePoint, it's not possible to use name and password to grant user access.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer. I couldn`t find anything on this topic either. 
Do you happen to know if it would be possible with the framework "msal"?